# javascript in perl code

Tags: perl, json

i using javascript file (json2.js) in perl-cgi code with apache. but when i run it on browser, its unable to find the source and return following error;
'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)'

my doumentroot path is : /srv/www/cgi-bin and scripts' path: /srv/www/cgi-bin/scripts

i doing this;

```
 print "<script type='text/javascript' src='./scripts/json2.js'></script>"; # Line 1
    print "<script type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript'>
    function setDetails(o,json_arrRef,arrSize){
            alert('hello='+arrSize+' || ref='+json_arrRef); // till here it works fine
            var json_obj = JSON.parse(json_arrRef);     
    }
    </script>";
```

if I edit Line 1 as

```
print "<script type='javascript' src='./scripts/json2.js'></script>";
```

it finds the source but gives following error when 'JSON.parse()' is called;
'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL'

am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

- **Don't** put static files anywhere in or below */cgi-bin/* as servers are often configured to treat that path is a special way
- **Do** get your type attributes correct, the content-type for JavaScript is *text/javascript* and not just *javascript* (technically speaking it should be *application/javascript*, but pretend it is *text/javascript* for the sake of browsers)
- **Don't** compare JavaScript errors in the browser with Perl code and **do** look at what the webserver is outputting (i.e. the HTML and JavaScript source and/or which requests give 404 or other HTTP error codes)

Comment: thanks David,
1. I put the script files on the document root but the result is same.
2. I already tried with these option (application/javascript and text/javascript) but no effects.
3. http 404 was due to Javascript file for sure

Comment: ok instead of using JSON.parse() I tried with eval and it is working fine. i downloaded the json2.js from json.org and i don't know why it has a problem.
but anyway thanks David

Comment: That would be because your JSON is invalid (JSON being a tiny subset of JavaScript). Test it with http://www.jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

Replace "./scripts/json2.js" with "/scripts/json2.js".